# Simple question in Rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A,U \in {M_n}$ and $U$ is unitary matrix.Is this true that $Rank(AU)=Rank(A)$?

Comment: You can relax $U$ to just being invertible.

Comment: you dont need unitary, all you need is invertibility of $U$ for $rank(AU) = rank(A).$

Answer (score 3):

If $U$ is a unitary matrix, then it is invertible.

If $B$ is any invertible matrix, then image$(AB)$=image$(A)$ because  image$(B)=\mathbb C^n$.

In particular, rank$(AB)$=rank$(A)$.